# Issue with pushing same option in selects array if the option added already exists in array

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js, dynamic, dropdown

When I add a new dynamic select and I choose the same option that was already in the selects array.

Example:

```
{ id: '1', name: 'Contact Info > Provide Email Address', value: '0.05' }
```

I get the default option that was

```
{ id: '0', name: 'Please Select an action', value: '0' }
```

but I want to get the option that was selected by me that was

```
{ id: '1', name: 'Contact Info > Provide Email Address', value: '0.05' }
```

So I can't pass the same value in selects array multiple times.

My Code

```
<div class="col-span-6 grid md:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-6 gap-2 mt-5 px-5 py-2 bg-gray-50 shadow rounded">
    <div class="mt-2 col-span-6 md:col-span-3" v-for="(select, index) in selects" :key="index">
        <label for="actions" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-2">
        Actions: <span v-if="index > 0">(Optional)</span>
        </label>
        <div class="flex justify-center mt-1 gap-2">
            <select v-model="select.id" @change="changeOption(select.id, select.id)" name="actions[]" class="appearance-none rounded-md relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm" placeholder="Task Action">
                <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.id" :value="option.id" disabled>{{ option.name }}</option>
            </select>
            <button @click.prevent="remove(index)" v-if="index > 0" class="bg-red-50 text-red-600 px-2 py-2 rounded">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 18 18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                </svg>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-span-6">
        <button @click.prevent="addselect(index)" class="bg-green-600 text-white px-2 py-2 mt-3 rounded">Add Actions</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            selectedActions: [],
            options: [{
                    id: '0',
                    name: 'Please Select an action',
                    value: '0'
                },
                {
                    id: '1',
                    name: 'Contact Info > Provide Email Address',
                    value: '0.05'
                },
                {
                    id: '2',
                    name: 'Contact Info > Provide Phone Number',
                    value: '0.05'
                },
                {
                    id: '3',
                    name: 'Contact Info > Provide Zip Code',
                    value: '0.02'
                },
                {
                    id: '4',
                    name: 'Engagement > Copy and paste something',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '5',
                    name: 'Engagement > Click on an Ad',
                    value: '0.02'
                },
                {
                    id: '6',
                    name: 'Engagement > Click on an Button',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '7',
                    name: 'Engagement > Copy & Paste a comment',
                    value: '0.03'
                },
                {
                    id: '8',
                    name: 'Engagement > Stay on a page per 1 minute',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '9',
                    name: 'Engagement > Fill out a form up to 5 fields',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '10',
                    name: 'Engagement > Watch a video per 1 minute',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '11',
                    name: 'Engagement > Search for something',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '12',
                    name: 'Engagement > Make a Faucet Claim',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '13',
                    name: 'Engagement > Use App/Website per 1 minute',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '14',
                    name: 'Engagement > Give a Star Rating',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '15',
                    name: 'Engagement > Refresh the page',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '16',
                    name: 'Engagement > Vote',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '17',
                    name: 'Engagement > Complete a Quiz per 5 questions',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '18',
                    name: 'Mobile Apps > Install and Open',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '19',
                    name: 'Mobile Apps > Play a Game',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '20',
                    name: 'Mobile Apps > Reach a level in a game',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '21',
                    name: 'Mobile Apps > Give Honest App Rating (50 word max)',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '22',
                    name: 'Mobile Apps > Give Honest App Rating (25 word max)',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '23',
                    name: 'Other > SMS Verification',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '24',
                    name: 'Other > Record a video per 1 minute',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '25',
                    name: 'Other > Confirm Email',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '26',
                    name: 'Other > KYC Submit',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '27',
                    name: 'Other > Complete one survey or offer up to $1',
                    value: '1'
                },
                {
                    id: '28',
                    name: 'Other > Download & Install Desktop Software',
                    value: '0.2'
                },
                {
                    id: '29',
                    name: 'Other > Install Browser Extension',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '30',
                    name: 'Other > Free Trial',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '31',
                    name: 'Other > Complete one survey or offer up to $0.20',
                    value: '0.2'
                },
                {
                    id: '32',
                    name: 'Register > Signup with Social Media',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '33',
                    name: 'Register > Signup with Email or Social Media',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '34',
                    name: 'Social Media > Like',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '35',
                    name: 'Social Media > Upvote',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '36',
                    name: 'Social Media > Follow',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '37',
                    name: 'Social Media > Subscribe',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '38',
                    name: 'Social Media > Save button click',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '39',
                    name: 'Social Media > Add as friend',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '40',
                    name: 'Social Media > Share or Retweet',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '41',
                    name: 'Social Media > Direct Message',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '42',
                    name: 'Social Media > Post on Wall/Timeline',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '43',
                    name: 'Social Media > Tag a Friend',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '44',
                    name: 'Social Media > Connect Social Media Account',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '45',
                    name: 'Writing > Write a unique comment per 10 words',
                    value: '0.01'
                },
                {
                    id: '46',
                    name: 'Writing > Write something per 100 words',
                    value: '0.01'
                }
            ],
            selects: [{
                id: '0'
            }],
        }
    },
    created() {
        if (this.$route.params.id) {
            axios.get(`/api/advertiser/task/${this.$route.params.id}`).then(res => {

                const actionsData = JSON.parse(res.data.actions);
                this.selects = actionsData.map(action => ({
                    id: action.id,
                    name: action.name,
                    value: action.value
                }));

            })
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addselect() {
            //this.selects.push({id: 0})
            const newSelectId = '0';
            const correspondingOption = this.options.find(option => option.id === newSelectId);

            if (correspondingOption) {
                this.selects.push({
                    id: newSelectId,
                    name: correspondingOption.name,
                    value: correspondingOption.value,
                });

                console.log('corresponding', correspondingOption)
            }

        },


        changeOption(selectId, newOptionId) {
            // console.log('Change Option: selectId', selectId, 'newOptionId', newOptionId);

            const selectIndex = this.selects.findIndex((select) => select.id === selectId);
            //console.log('Selectedindex', selectIndex)

            setTimeout(() => {
                const selectedOption = this.options.find((option) => option.id === newOptionId);

                console.log(selectedOption)

                if (selectedOption) { //&& selectIndex !== -1
                    const updatedSelect = {
                        id: selectId,
                        name: selectedOption.name,
                        value: selectedOption.value,
                    };
                    //this.selects.push(updatedSelect)
                    console.log('Updated', updatedSelect)

                    // Update both arrays
                    this.selects[selectIndex] = updatedSelect;

                    console.log('blb', this.selects)

                    const actionIndex = this.selectedActions.findIndex((action) => action.id === selectId);
                    if (actionIndex !== -1) {
                        this.selectedActions[actionIndex] = updatedSelect;
                    } else {
                        this.selectedActions.push(updatedSelect);
                    }

                    //this.selects = [...this.selects];
                    //this.selectedActions = [...this.selectedActions];
                }

                console.log('Action changed', this.selects);
            }, 0);
        },


        remove(index) {
            this.selects.splice(index, 1);
            this.selectedActions.splice(index, 1);
        },
        edittask() {
            const formData = new FormData();

            const formattedSelects = this.selects.map((select) => ({
                //id: select.id,
                name: select.name,
                value: select.value,
            }));
            //const actionsToSubmit = this.selectedActions.length > 0 ? this.selectedActions : this.selects;
            formData.append('actions', JSON.stringify(formattedSelects));


            const config = {
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            }

            axios.post('/api/advertiser/update/task/' + this.$route.params.id, formData, config).then(res => {
                    console.log(res.data)
                    //Show success toast.
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error)
                });

        },
        onFileChange(e) {
            const file = e.target.files[0];
            if (file) {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = () => {
                    this.file = file;
                    this.preview = reader.result;
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        totalprice() {
            return this.selects.reduce((sum, select) => {
                const selectedOption = this.options.find(option => option.id === select.id)
                return sum + (selectedOption ? parseFloat(selectedOption.value) : 0);
            }, 0).toFixed(2);
        },

    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question not so clear, but I assume you mean about the `addselect` method where you push new item to it.

If so, You can simply grab the last item from `this.selects` then push a `cloned` copy of it back to `this.selects`.

e.i.

```
methods: {
    .
    .
    .
    addselect() {
        
        //grab the last select object
        const lastSelected = this.selects[this.selects.length - 1]
        
        // dont push the lastSelected directly in the array or your select.id model will be messed-up
        // instead, clone it or manually assign key:value pair
        // just using `parse` and `stringify` to clone lastSelected, 
        this.selects.push( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(lastSelected) ) )
        
    },
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Yes but if I chose an option that already was selected, then is not push the option selected is push the default one with id:0. Like I want a user to allow adding same option more time.

Comment: I dont really understand what mean by hat, you need to be more clear, the code I provided does not have default, it grabs the last item thats  on `this.selects` array

Comment: Your code work but is not pass the option id in array ````[{"name":"Contact Info > Provide Email Address","value":"0.05"},{"name":"Contact Info > Provide Phone Number","value":"0.05"},{"name":"Engagement > Give a Star Rating","value":"0.01"},{"name":"Engagement > Click on an Button","value":"0.01"},{"name":"Engagement > Click on an Button","value":"0.01"}]````

Comment: the code I provided does not create anything, it simply cloned an existing object data you have,  then push it back to `this.selects` array, you need to properly understand how you construct your own data. even so, you are providing output without even explaining how you get them

Comment: ok but can u help me to get also the id because if i save this data in database and then when i grab it again all dynamic selects was empty,

Comment: So currently this is my selects list ````0
: 
{id: '1', name: 'Contact Info > Provide Email Address', value: '0.05'}
```` , now i gonna push new select in selects array then chose an option that already in the list above. ````0
: 
{id: '1', name: 'Contact Info > Provide Email Address', value: '0.05'}
1
: 
{id: '1', name: 'Please Select an action', value: '0'}````  but as u see there is adding the {id: '1', name: 'Please Select an action', value: '0'} instead of {id: '1', name: 'Contact Info > Provide Email Address', value: '0.05'} because the option is already in list already.

Comment: no, that doesn't make sense,  if you have the `addselect` as what I outlined above, it just grabs the last item of `this.selects` and cloned it then push as new item of `this.selects`. the object data like select.id as you mentioned is irrelevant in array push, all that matters is the item index

Comment: ok but then when i refresh the edit page  then all dropdown in page was empty. Even if i try to add new option in database it save only name and value.

Comment: My idea is better check my code how is working when adding new dynamic select and chosing the same option 2 times.